# I found a recurring pattern in python. But now I need to find the pattern that recurs

Tags: python-3.x

I made a regex to see if there is a recurring pattern in a string. But I also need to print what the pattern is. Here is and example and my code:

```
import re
regex1 = re.compile(r'\b(\d+)\1+\b')
x = input()
match = re.search(regex1,x)

if match:
    print(f"The number {x} is periodic and its pattern is {#this is where I need to print the pattern that recurs}")
else:
    print(f"The number {x} isn't periodic")
```

Comment: it just prints the original string

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
import re
regex1 = re.compile(r'\b(\d+)\1+\b')
x = input()
match = re.search(regex1,x)

if match:
    print(f"The number {x} is periodic and its period is {re.findall(regex1, x)[0]}")
else:
    print(f"The number {x} is NOT periodic")
```

Thanks